# numpy multivariate_normal bug when dimension too high

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a homework assignment and I noticed that when the dimension of mean and covariance is very high, `multivariate_normal` will occupy all CPU forever, without generating any results.

An example code snippet,

```
cov_true  = np.eye(p)
mean_true = np.zeros(p)
beta_true = multivariate_normal(mean_true, cov_true, size=1).T
```

when `p=5000`, this will run forever. 
environment, python3.4 and python3.5, numpy 1.11.0

Is it really a bug or did I miss something?

Comment: It works for me. Same versions. change the 3rd line to this see if it works:

`beta_true = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_true, cov_true, size=1).T`

Comment: yes, just different import, how long does it take for you to run this line?

Comment: Does "yes" means it worked and didn't take 100% cpu? mine: 
`--- 15.3049829006 seconds ---`

Comment: Oh, I used a different import, `from np.random import multivariate_normal`, yes, I mean using 100% CPU, on my 13' MacBook pro, `real 0m53.319s, user 1m40.845s, sys 0m2.128s`, and on a modern workstation, it is slightly better, but it uses all 48 cores, I can't understand why. @Yugi

Comment: I think there must be something wrong if your time is 15 seconds, my time is 50 seconds, are you using p=5000? and my test program is just import, `p=5000` and these three lines.

Comment: Yes I used p=5000. Have you tested with python2.7 ?

Comment: Oh, I used Python3.5 with numpy 1.11.0, let me try Python 2.7.

Comment: In your situation, does the program occupies all CPU cores? Is the function internally multithread?

Comment: @Yugi just tested with python2.7 and numpy 1.11.0, `real 0m45.638s user 5m49.364s sys 0m12.116s`, my testing program http://pastebin.com/CyKD7NXj, what's your test environment, including numpy version?

Comment: It takes almost half of the CPU cores on the workstation i'm working on. I tested on a Xenon CPU with 32 cores. I tested on my home corei7 laptop with python 2.7 and the time is : `47.385000`. My numpy version is also as same as you. Is this time too long for you ? what is your main goal ?

Comment: 47s is similar to mine. I don't understand why it will take so long and it doesn't make too much difference when I run it on 48 core machine and 4 core machine while it eats all cores. I guess it might be a bug?

Comment: 50 seconds is not forever.

Comment: Sorry, original I have a loop around it, these lines are called hundred of times, so I said forever, maybe I should change it. Thank you for pointing out @Goyo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What takes so much time?**

To account for relations between variables NumPy [computes the singular value decomposition](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.2/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4716) of your covariance matrix and this takes the majority of the time (the [underlying GESDD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html) is in general Θ(n<sup>3</sup>), and 5000<sup>3</sup> is already a bit).

**How can things be sped up?**

In the simplest case with all variables independent, you could just use [`random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.normal.html):

```
from numpy.random import normal

sample = normal(means, deviations, len(means))
```

Otherwise, if your covariance matrix happens to be full rank (hence positive-definite), supplant `svd` with [`cholesky`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cholesky.html) (still Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) in general, but with a smaller constant):

```
from numpy.random import standard_normal
from scipy.linalg import cholesky

l = cholesky(covariances, check_finite=False, overwrite_a=True)
sample = means + l.dot(standard_normal(len(means)))
```

If the matrix may be singular (as is sometimes the case), then either wrap [SPSTRF](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/dfc/spstrf_8f_a31a91fe2c1289d31db2f0733617c8fb7.html#a31a91fe2c1289d31db2f0733617c8fb7) or consider helping with [scipy#6202](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6202).

Cholesky will likely be noticeably faster, but if that's not sufficient, then further you could research if if it wouldn't be possible to decompose the matrix analytically, or try using a different base library (such as ACML, MKL, or cuSOLVER).

Comment: It reports error, `sample = normal(mean_true, cov_true, len(mean_true))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1495, in mtrand.RandomState.normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:10068)
ValueError: scale <= 0
`

Comment: You can use something like `np.sqrt(cov_true.diagonal())` to pick standard deviations from the covariance matrix. The first method is only correct if all off-diagonal entries are zero.

Comment: @wrwrwr does that mean that the complexity is *constant* in the number of samples, i.e. `np.random.multivariate_normal(size=100)` isn't too much slower than `np.random.multivariate_normal(size=10)`? Or is it *linear* in the `size`?